# error C2039:'serialize': is not a member of 'boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::electric_potential,double>'

Tags: c++, dictionary, serialization, boost, boost-units

How can I serialize a map with type electric_potential and double ??
In my code I have put these headers:

```
#include <boost/serialization/complex.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/units/physical_dimensions/electric_potential.hpp>

template<class Archive, class T> 
static void serialize( Archive & ar, T & t, const unsigned int file_version ){ 
  t.serialize(ar, file_version); 
}
extern "C++" class Data_substation_AC2 : public Data_OG
{
private:
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Data_OG);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_primary_voltage);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_secondary_voltage);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_impedance1);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_impedance2);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_location);
}
std::string                                                   _name;        
bu::quantity<si::electric_potential>                          _primary_voltage;
bu::quantity<si::electric_potential>                          _secondary_voltage;
bu::quantity<si::resistance, std::complex<double>>            _impedance1;
bu::quantity<si::resistance, std::complex<double>>            _impedance2;
Data_location                                                 _location;
```

I tried all the headers but still I have this error:

```
error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'boost::units::
quantity<boost::units::si::electric_potential,double>'
```

I am looking for the most simple way to solve this.
Thanks
[in this picture the code when i use the type electrical_potential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvwuh.jpg)

Comment: Show the code that causes the compilation error.

Comment: in the class access.hpp: in this function                              template<class Archive, class T>
    static void serialize(
        Archive & ar, 
        T & t, 
        const unsigned int file_version
    ){
                t.serialize(ar, file_version);
    }

Comment: Edit your original post to include your code

Comment: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::access::serialize<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled                                                              with                                                                                                            [
             Archive=boost::archive::xml_oarchive  ,          T=boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::electric_potential,double>          ]

Comment: You need to give a complete, self-contained and concise example that reproduces the issue. To me it looks like you are passing a `boost::units::
quantity` type into your `serialize` function and that this type does not have the method `serialise`. I suspect that you are new to templates, and that what you have is not what you wanted to do. Describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: where i can put the method serialize to this type ??

Comment: in my original post link of picture of my code

Comment: here is my code:                                                                             extern "C++" class Data_substation_AC2 : public Data_OG
{private:
 friend class boost::serialization::access;
 template<class Archive>
 void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Data_OG);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_primary_voltage);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_impedance1);
 }
 bu::quantity<si::electric_potential>      _primary_voltage;
 bu::quantity<si::resistance, std::complex<double>>      _impedance1;

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see what the problem could be. The fact that you don't show a complete, self-contained sample means I can't help you realize the problem, except by showing what I did to make it work:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60713df3d6f76c08)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/complex.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_unit.hpp>
#include <boost/units/io.hpp>
#include <boost/units/physical_dimensions/electric_potential.hpp>
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>
#include <boost/units/unit.hpp>

namespace bu = boost::units;
namespace si = bu::si;

//template<class Archive, class T> 
//static void serialize( Archive & ar, T & t, const unsigned int file_version ){ 
    //t.serialize(ar, file_version); 
//}

struct Data_OG{
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &, const unsigned int) { } 
};
struct Data_location {
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive &, const unsigned int) { }
};

class Data_substation_AC2 : public Data_OG
{
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int) {
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Data_OG);
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_primary_voltage);
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_secondary_voltage);
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_impedance1);
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_impedance2);
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_location);
            }
        std::string                                                   _name;        
        bu::quantity<si::electric_potential>                          _primary_voltage;
        bu::quantity<si::electric_potential>                          _secondary_voltage;
        bu::quantity<si::resistance, std::complex<double>>            _impedance1;
        bu::quantity<si::resistance, std::complex<double>>            _impedance2;
        Data_location _location;
};

int main() {
    Data_substation_AC2 dsac2;

    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(dsac2);
}
```

Prints

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
    <boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="14">
    <dsac2 class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <Data_OG class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0"></Data_OG>
        <_primary_voltage class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <value>0.00000000000000000e+00</value>
        </_primary_voltage>
        <_secondary_voltage>
            <value>0.00000000000000000e+00</value>
        </_secondary_voltage>
        <_impedance1 class_id="3" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <value>
                <real>0.00000000000000000e+00</real>
                <imag>0.00000000000000000e+00</imag>
            </value>
        </_impedance1>
        <_impedance2>
            <value>
                <real>0.00000000000000000e+00</real>
                <imag>0.00000000000000000e+00</imag>
            </value>
        </_impedance2>
        <_location class_id="4" tracking_level="0" version="0"></_location>
    </dsac2>
    </boost_serialization>
```